# Tricky SQL query

Tags: sql, select

I have to run a sql command in our database and I can't figure this one out. Here is what is needed:

"Show the names of vendors who have sold us an item more than once.  List the vendor, item, and the number of times ordered.  Suppose a vendor sold 8 of item 240 on Dec 1 and 12 of item 240 on Dec 30; this counts as two total orders of item 240 (not 20)."

[image: Here is our DB]
Here is what I have so far. I know it is super wrong but I don't know how to make it right.

```
    select v.VENDORID, poi.PARTNUM, count (po.PONUM)
    from vendor v, purchaseorder po, poitems poi
    where v.VENDORID=po.VENDORID and po.PONUM=poi.PONUM
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: Smells like homework long way.

Comment: Shouldn't the vendors and the parts be connected? What I mean is doesn't the vendor sell the part?

Comment: You're not grouping on anything. Group by vendor id

Comment: Can you trim that picture a little. Too much white.

Comment: The description is very vague, as is often the case with poorly worded homework! That's why college profs don't have real jobs. Do multiple orders for the same part on the same date constitute a single "order?" The description would imply that this is the case - but, I bet this wasn't the intention.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing HAVING and GROUP BY in the query. The query should be something like:

```
SELECT v.name, poi.PARTNUM, count (po.PONUM)
FROM vendor v
LEFT JOIN purchaseorder po ON (v.vendorid=po.vendorid)
LEFT JOIN poitems poi ON (po.PONUM=poi.PONUM)
WHERE poi.PARTNUM IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY (v.vendorID, poi.partnum)
HAVING COUNT(po.ponum) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this query works for you:

```
Select name
,description
,count(quantity)
from parts p
,(Select a.vendorid,name,ponum from purchaseorders a,
(Select vendorid,count(*) from purchaseorders 
--All vendors who have purchased more then once
group by vendorid having count(vendorid)>1) b
,vendor v
where a.vendorid=b.vendorid
and v.vendorid=a.vendorid) o
,(select vendorid,o.ponum,partnum,count(partnum) quantity 
--the quantity of orders     placed
from poitems p ,purchaseorders o
where o.ponum=p.ponum
group by vendorid,partnum,o.ponum) i
where i.vendorid=o.vendorid
and p.partnum=i.partnum
and i.ponum=o.ponum
group by name,description
```